# how can I prevent the navigation of the anchor tag that is a parent of a button from being executed without using preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a link and I want when I click on any part of the link to do the normal navigation, except when I click on the button(I know this can be achieved using `preventDefault()`).

I am using `voiceover` on ios(screen reader), the `preventDefault()` does not work in this mode when I tap on the button(navigation is done ignoring the preventDefault()), so I would like to find a strategy to keep my navigation when the button has not been tapped, and that when the button is tapped it does not continue with the navigation of the anchor tag.

How can I do this?

```js
function clickedButton(){
 console.log("click");
  alert("click")
}
```

```css
body,html{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

#mainLink{
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" id="mainLink">
    <button onclick="clickedButton()">click</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you simply fix the HTML so that the button isn't in an anchor tag? That seems like its the simplest solution as I'm sure whatever purpose the button is playing, it can be done in other ways.

Comment: @imvain2 is for accessibility issues, this is something like a card, and should be marked as an anchor tag.  In any case, I can't modify my code :( it's a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.stopPropagation()` method instead. Then when you click the button the event will not bubble to the parent element.

If you have multiple handlers on the same event then you should use the `.stopImmediatePropagation()`to stop all the handlers from bubbling the event.